# SQL - Filter rows with the same foreign key as a group

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to filter rows with the same foreign ID as a whole group. 
(Meaning that WHERE col1 = 'foo' AND col1 = 'bar' would be applicable to the whole group, and would only return foreign IDs where col1 have rows with 'foo' and 'bar')

I have table with pageviews. Each pageview contains its url, and is a part of a user session. I need to filter only sessions which pageviews contains some words. 
Let's say I want to filter sessions where the user visited both '/basket-step-1' and '/basket-finish'. (it has to work also with negation, ie visited step-1  but didn't visit finish)

I cannot simply use JOIN and then WHERE on the pageview.url because one pageview can never contain multiple urls.

something like this would work in theory:

```
SELECT * FROM session WHERE id IN 
(
    SELECT session_id FROM pageview 
    GROUP BY session_id 
    HAVING array_agg(url) ILIKE '%step-1%' AND ILIKE '%finish%'
)
```

however, you cannot use ILIKE in HAVING and would probably be quite slow. I'm now out of ideas as how to approach creating this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `having` along with conditional aggregation:

```
select s.*
from session s
where s.id in (select session_id
               from pageview pv
               group by session_id
               having sum(case when url ilike '%step-1%' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
                      sum(case when url ilike '%finish%' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             );
```

If you wanted negation, you would just use `= 0` instead of `> 0`.